# C#: Holding a collection of handler objects and finding the right one

Tags: c#, generics

So I have an interface called `IWorkItem` that is implemented in `WorkA`, `WorkB` and many other classes.

```
public interface IWorker<T> where T : IWorkItem
{
    void Process(T item);
}
```

The `IWorker<T>` interface is implemented in `WorkerA` (`IWorker<WorkA>`), `WorkerB` (`IWorker<WorkB>`) and many other classes.

```
public static void ProcessWorkItem(IWorkItem item)
{
    (/* find the right worker */).Process(item);
}
```

Now my problem is: How do find a worker object that is able to process the given `IWorkItem`?

My first attempts look like this, but the generic type arguments are a problem:

```
public static class WorkerRepository
{
    private static Dictionary<Type, IWorker<???>> RegisteredWorkers =
        new Dictionary<Type, IWorker<???>>();

    public static void RegisterWorker(IWorker<???> worker)
    {
        var handled = from iface in worker.GetType().GetInterfaces()
                      where iface.IsGenericType
                      where iface.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IWorker<>)
                      select iface.GetGenericArguments()[0];
        foreach (var type in handled)
            if (!RegisteredWorkers.ContainsKey(type))
                RegisteredWorkers[type] = worker;
    }

    public static void ProcessWorkItem(IWorkItem item)
    {
        RegisteredWorkers[item.getType()].Process(item);
    }
}
```

So I have the `Dictionary` that contains the workers. Which type argument do I need here? In Java I could just use `? extends IWorkItem`, but do I do that in C#?
Then there is `RegisterWorker`. You would probably suggest a generic type argument for the entire method, like `RegisterWorker<T>(IWorker<T> worker)`. However, that also won't work, since I would like to dynamically load, instantiate and register Workers.

Is this even the right approach or is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Interface names should start with `I`. Your naming convention is really confusing.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Renamed.

Comment: does `WorkerRepository` have to be static? or can i make it a generic class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want something like this:

```
private static Dictionary<Type, object> RegisteredWorkers = new Dictionary<Type, object>();

public static void RegisterWorker(object worker)
{
    var handled = from iface in worker.GetType().GetInterfaces()
                  where iface.IsGenericType
                  where iface.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Worker<>)
                  select iface.GetGenericArguments()[0];
    foreach (var type in handled)
        if (!RegisteredWorkers.ContainsKey(type))
            RegisteredWorkers[type] = worker;
}

public static void ProcessWorkItem(WorkItem item)
{
    object handler = RegisteredWorkers[item.getType()];
    Type workerType = typeof(Worker<>).MakeGenericType(item.GetType());
    MethodInfo processMethod = workerType.GetMethod("Process");
    processMethod.Invoke(handler, new object[] { item });
}
```

If you don't want to invoke the handlers through reflection each time you can generate an `Action<IWorkItem>` handler when you register the handler:

```
public void RegisterHandler(object handler)
{
    var handled = from iface in handler.GetType().GetInterfaces()
                  where iface.IsGenericType
                  where iface.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IWorker<>)
                  select iface.GetGenericArguments()[0];

    foreach (var type in handled)
    {
        if (!RegisteredWorkers.ContainsKey(type))
        {
            Action<IWorkItem> handleAction = HandlerAction(type, handler);
            RegisteredWorkers[type] = handleAction;
        }
    }   
}

public void Process(IWorkItem item)
{
    Action<IWorkItem> handleAction = RegisteredWorkers[item.GetType()];
    handleAction(item);
}

private static Action<IWorkItem> HandlerAction(Type itemType, object handler)
{
    var paramExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IWorkItem));
    var castExpr = Expression.Convert(paramExpr, itemType);
    MethodInfo processMethod = typeof(IWorker<>).MakeGenericType(itemType).GetMethod("Process");
    var invokeExpr = Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(handler), processMethod, castExpr);

    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Action<IWorkItem>>(invokeExpr, paramExpr);
    return lambda.Compile();
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is basically what I want. However, reflections is not really famous for great performance and I'm going to process a lot of work items in a tight loop. Is there really no faster way?

Comment: @main-- You could create an `Action` delegate when registering the handler and invoke that. I'll add an example.

Comment: Shouldn't `paramExpr` in the fourth line of `HandlerAction` be `handler` instead?

Answer (score 2):

I made a few changes but got a solution where you can keep things generic (instead of using `object`s). Not sure if you even care, but thought to add it as answer and let you decide.

I also wrote a test to check if it actually works, you should be able to copy/paste it.

```
[TestFixture]
public class WorkerThing
{
    [Test]
    public void RegisterAndRetrieveWorkers()
    {
        var repo = new WorkerRepository();
        repo.RegisterWorker(new WorkerA());
        var workerA = repo.RetrieveWorkerForWorkItem(new WorkItemA());
        Assert.IsTrue(workerA is WorkerA);

        repo.RegisterWorker(new WorkerB());
        var workerB = repo.RetrieveWorkerForWorkItem(new WorkItemB());
        Assert.IsTrue(workerB is WorkerB);
    }
}
```

The `WorkerRepository` class.

```
public class WorkerRepository
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, IWorker<IWorkItem>> _registeredWorkers =
        new Dictionary<Type, IWorker<IWorkItem>>();

    public void RegisterWorker(IWorker<IWorkItem> worker)
    {
        var type = (from iface in worker.GetType().GetInterfaces()
                      where iface.IsGenericType
                      where iface.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IWorker<>)
                      select iface.GetGenericArguments()[0]).First();

        if (!_registeredWorkers.ContainsKey(type))
        {
            _registeredWorkers[type] = worker;
        }
    }

    // You don't need this method, just added it to check if I indeed retrieved the correct type
    //
    public IWorker<IWorkItem> RetrieveWorkerForWorkItem(IWorkItem item)
    {
        var type = item.GetType();
        var registeredWorker = _registeredWorkers[type];
        return registeredWorker;
    }

    public void ProcessWorkItem(IWorkItem item)
    {
        var type = item.GetType();
        var registeredWorker = _registeredWorkers[type];
        registeredWorker.Process(item);
    }
}
```

The work item interfaces & classes.

```
public interface IWorkItem
{
}

public class WorkItemA : IWorkItem
{
}

public class WorkItemB : IWorkItem
{
}
```

And here I added the `out` keyword to allow covariance typing on the interface. That way you can convert `WorkerA` to `IWorker<IWorkItem>`. (as in the unit test example)

```
public interface IWorker<out T> where T : IWorkItem
{
    void Process(IWorkItem workItem);
}

public class WorkerA : IWorker<WorkItemA>
{
    public void Process(IWorkItem item)
    {
    }
}

public class WorkerB : IWorker<WorkItemB>
{
    public void Process(IWorkItem item)
    {
    }
}
```

No `object` dictionaries. No reflection. I hope the example is useful!

Cheers (and thx for the cool question, it kept me busy for a while :))

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but one important detail is missing: `IWorker.Process` no longer takes arguments of type `T` but now just `IWorkItem`. That basically bypasses the entire difficulty of this problem.

Comment: That's a big downside of this approach indeed. I tried to get passed this issue but I can't find a way... It almost seems a shortcoming of the language.

Comment: Probably they didn't allow it because there's simply no typesafe way to do this: You know that the method takes an argument that inherits from `IWorkItem` but for the language there's no way to tell whether an object is of that UNKNOWN type. In Java I could cast the generic type argument away, because Java generics are weak. But in C# I have to use reflection/a dynamic method to dynamically create the right cast.